# Run javascript after element is added to body

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a `<div>` element that does not appear on the page unless some function is activated. I want to remove this `<div>` after it appears on the page.

how do I run my JavaScript code when and only when this `<div>` element is added ?

I am new at this and would appreciate some help. Thanks.

ps. element is generated by jquery and only has classname.

Detailed explanation:

I implementing a excel export in an existing web application.
I am using a form surrounding filters for search and a ajaxgrid gridstate. 
This form is submitted to a controller that has the corresponding viewmodels.

My code for submitting the form is this:

```
$(function () {
    $('div.btn-group #export-citizen-list').on('click', function () {
        var gridstate = $('#citizenIndexGrid').ajaxgrid('getState');
        var form = $('#create-citizen-csv-file');

        // add ajaxgrid state to post data
        $.each(gridstate, function (k, v) {
            form.addAjaxgridHidden(k, v);
        });

        // submit entire form, with ajaxgrid state
        form.submit();

        // remove all hiddenfields that belongs to ajaxgrid
        form.find(":hidden.ajaxgrid").remove();
        document.getElementById("filterSearch").className = "default ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all";
        $('#filterSearch').removeAttr('disabled');
// function that removes unwanted <div> ---->$('.ajaxWorkingNotification').slideUp();
    })

    jQuery.fn.addAjaxgridHidden = function (name, value) {
        return this.each(function () {
            var input = $('<input>').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', name).attr('class', 'ajaxgrid').val(value);
            $(this).append($(input));
        });
    };
});
```

When I submit my form the excel is downloaded and the unwanted `<div>` is inserted in the DOM. The thing is that I don't know when the postback is returned in this case. And therefore I don't know when this `<div>` is inserted.

Hope this clarifies my issue.

Comment: Probably you can use Jquery's Hide and Show - http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp. Hide the element when page gets loaded, and when you want to display it then you can show it.

Comment: @ramiramilu the page is loaded. But the div is not inserted. It is only inserted when a button is pushed

Comment: In that case when you add the element through code, then why cant you execute the other code then and there itself. Probably you can explain your question in detail with example, then I can provide you a solution.

Comment: @ramiramilu question updated. hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
// Assuming your element is created by this line ...
$(".your_elements_class_name").ready(function() {
    // write code here
    // this is executed after the element is created and added to DOM
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by implement a listener on DOM node insertion event.

There was an explanation [here](https://davidwalsh.name/detect-node-insertion) on how to detect DOM node insertion & pure javascript code to demonstrate how it works

And if you like a jQuery version, then here is the sample code that I translated from above link.

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="addme" value="Add"/>
<div id="container">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes nodeInserted {  
    from { opacity: 0.99; }
    to { opacity: 1; }  
}

#container div#mydiv {
    animation-duration: 0.001s;
    animation-name: nodeInserted;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $('#addme').click(function () {
    var div = $('<div/>').attr('id', 'mydiv').html("Hello");
    $('#container').append(div);
  });

  var handler = function (e) {
    if (e.originalEvent.animationName == "nodeInserted")
        alert("An HTMLElement has been inserted to DOM tree !")
  };

  var eventSignature = 'MSAnimationStart';
  if ($.browser.webkit) eventSignature = 'webkitAnimationStart';
  if ($.browser.mozilla) eventSignature = 'animationstart';
  $(document).on(eventSignature, handler);
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ycLzg3LL/1/)

Comment: i have updated my question, i hope is clarifies my issue . Would this work still ?

Comment: This will always work no matter what & when the rubbish element is inserted to the DOM tree. Just replace `#container` & `div#mydiv` with your real locators, then you'll be fine.